# sql query to fetch first and last records of each month for two products

Tags: mysql, jsp

hello guys please i'm writing a query that can give me the first and last records of each month which is done but the case is i'm retrieving data for two products using the code below

```sql
SELECT u1.product, 
       v.month,
       v.mindt,
       u1.opens,
       v.maxdt,
       u2.closingStockvalue 
FROM ( SELECT month, MIN(date) mindt, MAX(date) maxdt 
       FROM closingstock 
       where product='PMS' 
       GROUP BY month) v 
JOIN closingstock u1 ON u1.date=v.mindt 
JOIN closingstock u2 ON u2.date=v.maxdt;
```

but the result is in the screen shot below and i want only the highlighted result please any solution for that the screenshot is below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YGV7.png)

Comment: [How to Properly Format SQL Code](https://dzone.com/articles/24-rules-to-the-sql-formatting-standard). I quote: _"Ignoring the SQL formatting standard can cause significant problems when you are collaborating with other programmers. Proper formatting helps your SQL code be easier to read and helps prevent errors when making changes to your code."_ Your formatting doesn't have to be perfect, but long queries on one line are almost unreadable, and don't fit into your screenshot.

Comment: Your highlight doesn't match your stated goal.  You said you wanted 2 records, you highlighted 1.  Can you be more specific with what -exactly- you're trying to return.

Comment: in the query there is a where clause for a particular product that's why i highlighted one

Comment: Again, you don't explain what you want.  Do you always want that product ID?  Do you want to pick any specific product?  You're not explaining what about the highlighted result makes it the one you want, and it makes no sense relative to the question you posted initially.  You say you're writing code to retrieve 2 products (which the code on no way does) and then you highlight one product in "what you want".  Which is it?  Two or one?  The code you wrote has literally no "pick a product" code in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT product, 
       v.month,
       v.mindt,
       u1.opens,
       v.maxdt,
       u2.closingStockvalue 
FROM ( SELECT product, `month`, MIN(`date`) mindt, MAX(`date`) maxdt 
       FROM closingstock 
       WHERE product IN ('Product 1', 'Product 2')  -- the list of needed products
       GROUP BY product, `month`) v 
JOIN closingstock u1 USING (product)
JOIN closingstock u2 USING (product)
WHERE u1.`date`=v.mindt
  AND u2.`date`=v.maxdt;
```

Comment: Great thanks dude it worked but i twisted it a little like this     SELECT u1.product, 
       v.month,
       v.mindt,
       u1.opens,
       v.maxdt,
       u2.closingStockvalue 
FROM ( SELECT product, `month`, MIN(`date`) mindt, MAX(`date`) maxdt 
       FROM closingstock 
       WHERE product IN ('Product 1', )  -- added the product
       GROUP BY product, `month`) v 
JOIN closingstock u1 USING (product)
JOIN closingstock u2 USING (product)
WHERE u1.`date`=v.mindt
  AND u2.`date`=v.maxdt;

Comment: @maxwellOwusu `.. WHERE product IN ('Product 1', ) ..` will cause an error due to excess comma - remove it.